# Dropdown list triggering required field validation when disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function here, when I disable the report field from the code below, I can't submit the form because the required field triggers, even though there is a selected value in the dropdown. When i remove the disabling of the list. I was able to submit the form:

```
window.onload = function()
{
var x = document.getElementById("jform_report");
x.disabled = true;  
}

jQuery('#jform_report').prop('disabled', true).trigger("chosen:updated");
```

[image]

What might be triggering the required field? I tried displaying the dropdown's value by using a alert box, It shows the correct selected value so I'm wondering why is the required field validation triggering.

here is the HTML code :

```
<input type="hidden" name="jform[report]" value="<?php echo $this->item->report; ?>" />

<div class="control-group">
    <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('report'); ?></div>
    <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('report'); ?></div>
</div>
```

When I click submit, it points to this line of code in the inspect element:

```
<a class="chzn-single" tabindex="-1"><span>Java</span><div><b></b></div></a>
```

does it have something to do with tabindex?

Comment: wow, downvoted so fast? I provided full description of my problem yet it got downvoted.

Comment: Please share your HTML code... Why downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

When you Disable your control, it suggests that the field is not selected, therefore if it is a required field and you have to disable it, make sure you put in a hidden field (with the same name as the required field) with the selected value. It will pass your validation

Comment: `code`<input type="hidden" name="jform[report]" value="<?php echo $this->item->report; ?>" />

@progrAmmar I have added this hidden field input in the html form. Is this what you mean

Comment: Yes, is the name attribute same as your dropdown? if it is the same, then may be you may try changing name of the dropdown when it's disabled, just in case if PHP finds it conflicting

Comment: <div class="control-group">
  <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('report'); ?></div>
  <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('report'); ?></div>
 </div>

I can't change the name of the dropdown since it is generated when the page loads. Here is the code above.

Comment: Can you share the output HTML? just the part where your dropdown comes

Comment: <select id="jform_report" name="jform[report]" class="inputbox chzn-done invalid" required="" aria-required="true" disabled="" aria-invalid="false" style="display: none;">
 <option value="2">C</option>
 <option value="1" selected="selected">Java</option>
</select>

I used inspect element to get this code. They share the same name. However when the dropdown is disabled, it still triggers the required field

Comment: in addition to jQuery('#jform_report').prop('disabled', true).trigger("chosen:updated"); you can also try jQuery('#jform_report').removeAttr('aria-required'); and see what happens

Comment: i added your code but it still does not work. It only works when I remove the disabling of the field.

Comment: In your HTML code, I do not see the hidden field with the same name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69165/discussion-between-lawrence-batuhan-and-programmar).